# Some errors when building Glibc LFS - are they harmless?

Tags: glibc, lfs

I've finished chapter 5. When I'm building glibc, I get some errors:

```
root:/sources/glibc-build# grep Error glibc-check-log
make[2]: *** [/sources/glibc-build/posix/tst-getaddrinfo4.out] Error 1
make[2]: [/sources/glibc-build/posix/annexc.out] Error 1 (ignored)
make[1]: *** [posix/tests] Error 2
make[2]: *** [/sources/glibc-build/nptl/tst-cond25.out] Error 1
make[1]: *** [nptl/tests] Error 2
make[2]: [/sources/glibc-build/conform/run-conformtest.out] Error 1 (ignored)
make: *** [check] Error 2
```

Are they harmless?
My LFS version is 7.4, and glibc version is 2.18

Comment: Considering you omitted the actual cause of the errors, who knows... they are almost definitely not harmless, though.

Comment: I can post full content of glibc-check-log, but it's very long.

Comment: At least post the output of `grep -C 2 Error glibc-check-log`.

Comment: @terdon In that file, there is very few new lines, but there is output: http://pastebin.com/8zALit0q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost errors are listed in LFS book as harmless and they appear nearly always, so I skipped to next paragraph.

Other are:

```
make[1]: *** [posix/tests] Error 2
```

and

```
make[1]: *** [nptl/tests] Error 2
```

That are general names of groups of errors that occured before.

Answer (score 0):

This thread titled: [Re: [lfs-dev] LFS Package Currency Check - 2013-08-13](https://www.mail-archive.com/lfs-dev@linuxfromscratch.org/msg18867.html) seems to show your issue.

*excerpt*

```
I did find a few check errors in the build:


090-coreutils:FAIL: tests/df/skip-rootfs.sh
090-coreutils:FAIL: tests/df/skip-rootfs.sh (exit: 1)

103-automake:FAIL: t/primary-prefix-invalid-couples.tap 280 - ... and 
with the same diagnostic of 'automake -a'
103-automake:# FAIL:  1

107-flex:Test test-bison-yylloc FAILED. See test-bison-yylloc/OUTPUT for 
details.
107-flex:Test test-bison-yylval FAILED. See test-bison-yylval/OUTPUT for 
details.

124-texinfo:FAIL: prove.sh

072-glibc:make[3]: *** [/sources/glibc-build/posix/tst-getaddrinfo4.out] 
Error 1
072-glibc:make[3]: [/sources/glibc-build/posix/annexc.out] Error 1 (ignored)
...
```

I didn't go through the entire thread, but perhaps your issue lies within this thread.

Comment: Thanks, but It isin't my issue. That errors seem to be harmless, so I'll close question.