# LFS-7.5 chapter 6.9 `make check` fails

Tags: linux, glibc, lfs

I am building and installing **glibc-2.19** in chapter 6.9 and I encountered this error while executing `TIMEOUTFACTOR=16 make -k check | tee glibc-check-log`:

> mv -f /sources/glibc-build/nptl/libpthread.so.jmprelT /sources/glibc-build/nptl/libpthread.so.jmprel
>   LC_ALL=C gawk -f ../scripts/localplt.awk /sources/glibc-build/libc.so.jmprel /sources/glibc-build/math/libm.so.jmprel /sources/glibc-build/rt/librt.so.jmprel /sources/glibc-build/dlfcn/libdl.so.jmprel /sources/glibc-build/resolv/libresolv.so.jmprel /sources/glibc-build/crypt/libcrypt.so.jmprel /sources/glibc-build/nptl/libpthread.so.jmprel | \
>     LC_ALL=C gawk -f ../scripts/check-localplt.awk ../sysdeps/generic/localplt.data - \
>   /sources/glibc-build/elf/check-localplt.out
>   env \
>   LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 \
>   LD_DEBUG=unused \
>   LD_PRELOAD= \
>   /sources/glibc-build/elf/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 \
>     --library-path /sources/glibc-build:/sources/glibc-build/math:/sources/glibc-build/elf:/sources/glibc-build/dlfcn:/sources/glibc-build/nss:/sources/glibc-build/nis:/sources/glibc-build/rt:/sources/glibc-build/resolv:/sources/glibc-build/crypt:/sources/glibc-build/nptl \
>     /sources/glibc-build/elf/testobj1.so > /sources/glibc-build/elf/tst-unused-dep.out
>   cmp /sources/glibc-build/elf/tst-unused-dep.out /dev/null > /dev/null
>   rm /sources/glibc-build/libc.dynsym
>   make[2]: Leaving directory '/sources/glibc-2.19/elf'
>   make[1]: Target 'check' not remade because of errors.
>   make[1]: Leaving directory '/sources/glibc-2.19'
>   Makefile:9: recipe for target 'check' failed
>   make: *** [check] Error 2

I understand that `make -k check` tells **make** to not stop if errors or warnings are encountered, implying that `make -k check` encountered something serious and hence exited with an error.

Should I be bothered with this error or is this because of the errors and warnings which were ignored. My worry is that it says that `Target 'check' not remade because of errors`.

Output of `grep Error glibc-check-log`:

> make[2]: *** [/sources/glibc-build/libio/tst-ftell-partial-wide.out] Error 1
>   make[1]: *** [libio/tests] Error 2
>   make[2]: *** [/sources/glibc-build/posix/tst-getaddrinfo4.out] Error 1
>   make[1]: *** [posix/tests] Error 2
>   make[2]: *** [/sources/glibc-build/rt/tst-cpuclock2.out] Error 1
>   make[1]: *** [rt/tests] Error 2
>   make: *** [check] Error 2

Similar questions have been asked in this [question_1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130734/lfs-7-5-glibc-2-19-compile-errors-at-section-6-9-are-they-fatal-to-my-lfs-bui), this [question_2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108080/some-errors-when-building-glibc-lfs-are-they-harmless) , [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.lfs.support/37991) and [lfs-mailing-lists](https://www.mail-archive.com/lfs-support@linuxfromscratch.org/msg21171.html). My problem is not with the output of `grep Error glibc-error-log`, but with `make check` failing.

Do I continue my build ignoring this? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors you're getting are all listed in the LFS book as known and safe to ignore.

Run `make check` again after the failure and it should complete without errors.

The reason it doesn't fail the second time is because it skips tests that have already been run (even the failed ones).